# libxml2 fails to handle CDATA in HTML correctly

Tags: html, xml, html-parsing, libxml2

I'm using libxml2.2.7.3 to parse html pages and I'm having difficulties getting it work correctly with CDATA in HTML. Here's the code:

```
xmlDocPtr doc = htmlReadMemory(data, length, "", NULL, 0);
xmlBufferPtr buffer = xmlBufferCreate();
xmlNodeDump(buffer, doc, doc->children, 0, 0);
printf("%s", (char*)buffer->content);
```

and the HTML data:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[
      document.write('</div>');
    //]]>
    </script>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

The parser erroneously recognizes the </div> inside the quotes as a real html tag and prints out error messages as follows:

```
:8: HTML parser error : Unexpected end tag : script
    </script>
             ^
:9: HTML parser error : Unexpected end tag : div
  </div>
        ^
```

And the result printed out and debugging also imply that parsing went wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[ 
    //<![CDATA[
      document.write(']]></script></div>');
    //]]>


</body></html>
```

So the question is, is this a bug of libxml2? Or am I doing something wrong?
Any insightful advices would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect an XML parser to parse SGML?

Comment: libxml2 also includes an HTML parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, the `<script>` element contains CDATA by definition, so `<![CDATA[` has no effect.

In short, the source document is broken.

That section would be more properly written as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.write('<\/div>');
</script>
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for the prompt answer! I understand the CDATA  part, but why should '</div>' be rewritten as '<\/div>' if <script> element contains CDATA by definition?

Comment: Since any end tag will terminate the CDATA section.

Comment: Excellent, you really saved my time. Thank you so much, David! One last question. I see the browsers like Chrome parse the code correctly in spite of the wrong usage of '</div>'. Would it be possible by any chance to make libxml2 parse the code correctly, for example, by specifying doctype differently? I'm fetching the html code from a server which is not mine, so there's no way I can modify the html code correctly..

Comment: I'd probably approach the problem by running the code through an HTML5 parser.

Comment: Does HTML5 not have the same problem?

Comment: HTML5 has different parsing rules. I wouldn't swear that it could cope with this, but I'd give it a shot.